# jQuery works on web browser but not on mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile

This works fine in web browsers, but it doesn't work on mobile browsers. What am I missing here? I can only add script to the page, I can not edit the select options at all. I have seen that .val or .change doesn't work on mobile browsers but I can not find a documented fix or some basic code that works across all platforms.

```
$("#CallTimeRange").on('keyup change select', (function () {
        
            var later = $('#CallTimeRange').val(); 
            var timezone = $('#TimeZone').val();
        if (later === 'select a time' || timezone ==='9') {
            
            $('#submitSchedule').css('display', 'none');
            
            return false;
        }else{
        
        $('#submitSchedule').css('display', 'block');
        
        return;
 
    }
      
  })); 


<select id="CallTimeRange" tabindex="3" name="CallTimeRange">
<option value="select a time">select a time</option>
<option value="6:00 AM-8:00 AM">6:00 AM-8:00 AM</option>
<option value="8:00 AM-10:00 AM">8:00 AM-10:00 AM</option>
<option value="10:00 AM-12:00 PM">10:00 AM-12:00 PM</option>
<option value="12:00 PM-2:00 PM">12:00 PM-2:00 PM</option>
<option value="2:00 PM-4:00 PM">2:00 PM-4:00 PM</option></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It might be easier to write a script to do that using the onchange

```
<select onchange="myFunction()">
```

This way you can do it using pure html  tags as per the sample below.
Just make the changes to the function according to your requirements.

```
   <script>
   window.addEventListener("resize", myFunction);

   function myFunction() {
                       var $myWidth = document.body.clientWidth;
                       $myWidth=($myWidth * (4 / 4));
                      var $myHeight= ($myWidth / (16/9));       // var myHeight="900.876976978";
                      $myHeight= Math.round($myHeight);
    
                   document.getElementById("Edit1").width = $myWidth -40;
                   document.getElementById("Edit1").height = $myHeight;
                     }
                      </script>
```

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to mention, I can not edit the select/ options at all, only add some jquery to the footer of the page.

Answer (score 0):

Write it all in vanilla javascript worked.